# Document similarity selfplagiarism

Tags: r, quanteda

I have thousands of small documents from 100 different authors.  Using `quanteda` package, I calculated cosine similarity between the authors with themselves. For example, author x has 100 texts, so I have come up with a 100 x 100 matrix of similarity. Author y has 50 texts, so I have come up with a 50 x 50 similarity matrix.

Now I want to compare these two authors. In other words, which author copies himself more? If I take the average the columns or rows and then average again the vector of means, I arrive at a number so I can compare these two means of means, but I am not sure if these proceeding is right. I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on what exactly is your quantity of interest. If this is a single summary of how similar are an author's documents to one another, then some distribution across the document similarities, within author, is probably your best means of comparing this quantity between authors.

You could save and plot the cosine similarities across an author's documents as a density, for instance, in addition to your strategy of summarising this distribution using a mean.  To capture the variance I would also characterise the standard deviation of this similarity.

I'd be cautious about calling cosine similarity within author as "self-plagiarism".  Cosine similarity computes a measure of distance across vector representations of bags of words, and is not viewed as a method for identifying "plagiarism".  In addition, there are very pejorative connotations to the term "plagiarism", which means the dishonest representation of someone else's ideas as your own.  (I don't even believe that the term "self-plagiarism" makes sense at all, but then I have academic colleagues who disagree.)

**Added:**

Consider the [**textreuse** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textreuse/index.html) for R, it is designed for the sort of text analysis of reuse that you are looking for.

I don't think Levenshtein distance is what you are looking for.  As the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) points out, the LD between *kitten* and *sitting* is 3, but this means absolutely nothing in substantive terms about their semantic relationship or one being an example of  "re-use" of the other.  An argument could be made that LD based on *words* might show re-use, but that's not how most algorithms e.g. http://turnitin.com implement detection for plagiarism.

Comment: Thank you very much. Some of my colleagues also disagree that I can use the word self-plagiarism and I might not use it in the final version of the paper. I am analyzing judicial decisions in criminal cases. Some judges have high productivity such that they decide three times cases as much as others. My hypothesis is that productivity is positively correlated with the rate of similarity between judges' own decisions because they might use the text of their previous decisions on new cases without scrutinizing them carefully. Do you think that I can use Levenshtein distance in this case?